# How to avoid xml header while concatenating xml files in ant script

Tags: java, xml, ant, xml-parsing

I am concatenating all the xml files in a folder into a single xml file in ant script. While concatenating the xml files, the header

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

in all xml files are getting appended in the output xmlfile.

Is there any way to avoid this header ?

```
  <concat destfile="${docbook.dir}/all-sections.xml"
      force="no">       
   <fileset dir="${docbook.dir}"
     includes="sections/*.xml"/>
   </concat>
```

Comment: This may help: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html

Comment: You asked this question a second time when it had been answered by @venkat He provided the additional filterchain that removed the xml header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a regex to discard the header:

```
<concat destfile="${docbook.dir}/all-sections.xml" force="no">       
    <fileset dir="${docbook.dir}" includes="sections/*.xml"/>
    <filterchain>
        <linecontainsregexp negate="true">
            <regexp pattern="&lt;\?xml version"/>
        </linecontainsregexp>
    </filterchain>  
 </concat>
```

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html

EDIT: If you want to keep the first occurrence of the header then this is an option:

```
<property name="first" value="true"/>

<concat destfile="${docbook.dir}/all-sections.xml">       
    <fileset dir="${docbook.dir}" includes="sections/*.xml"/>
    <filterchain>
        <scriptfilter language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            first = project.getProperty("first");
            if(self.getToken().indexOf("<\?xml version") != -1) {
                if(first == "true") {
                    project.setProperty("first", "false");
                } else {
                    self.setToken(null);
                }
            }
        ]]> 
        </scriptfilter>             
    </filterchain>
</concat>
```

Comment: It works out. Thank you. Is it possible to the have the value for first occurrence(not removing if found first) and then removing it if its repeated in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter chain.So you can use ' xml version' or 'encoding' to filter.

```
<filterchain>
         <linecontains>
          <contains value="xml version"/>
         </linecontains>
      </filterchain>
```

Then there is one Header that can be added as common.There you can give the common header.

```
<header filtering="no" trimleading="yes">
      ----Put  Header---
</header>
```

Function Ref:  https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html&ei=t1jfBWPU&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=717&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1456774849&sig=ALL1Aj6a3WOuua261FfWU1a1B-ULkTgOMw